# Efficient Android Animation

Tags: android, animation

My requirement is to show a slide-down animation of a list of 'n' views where n can be max 25.
Now there are 2 ways I can think of by which this can be done:

1. Take a loop of 'n' and animate all the 'n' views separately.
2. Wrap all the 'n' views inside a Linear/Relative layout and then animate only that parent layout.

What I think is that the 2nd way should be more efficient, but I'm not able to find any strong logical reason by which I can give preference to any of these methods over the other.